# What is the top speed of Weeping Angels?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

Sorry if this is a well-known bit of trivia, I've just started watching Doctor Who very recently and I couldn't find this anywhere.

- In the episode "Blink", the Doctor says the Weeping Angels are incredibly fast, but is it known exactly *how* fast they can be?
- In some instances their speed (based on how far they moved and how long they had to do it) seems to be at least a few hundred miles per hour.
- However, there are other instances where someone has their back turned for several seconds and they only move a foot or so. I suppose that could just be them choosing to move slower, but is the maximum speed known? Thanks!

Comment: They're known to slow down when close to their prey, enjoying the kill.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I figured it must be something like that to explain why they get so slow at close range

Comment: They move at the speed of plot but according to TV tropes, the fastest they've been observed moving (in Blink) is approximately 8 metres per second.

Comment: Note also that they can (apparently) fly through space unaided. That suggests that their top speed is vast.

Comment: @Richard Flying is bad if you could become solid (yet brittle) stone at any moment I guess.

Comment: Why don't you close your eyes and find out...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The full extent of the abilities of the Weeping Angels has never been depicted on the television show. Given what we have seen and can imply from the Doctor's conversations about them, they can be, when fully powered, formidable.

- In most of their appearances, the Angels are found to be in a hibernating state at their lowest power. This makes their corresponding slowness reasonable. Once they have begun to feed, their speed and their ability to manipulate their environment drawing energy from those surroundings improves. (TV: The Time of Angels / Flesh and Stone)
- With the Weeping Angels ability to convert themselves into energy and transmit themselves into the minds of viewers, theoretically, they can, at least, move as fast as a beam of light or as fast as the communication system of a species will allow them. Based in the quote: The image of an Angel IS an Angel. (TV: The Time of Angels), (PROSE: Touched by an Angel)

[image]

**We have seen Weeping Angels:**

- Alter the confines of a space so it cannot be entered and convert an image of an Angel into the threat of attack from an Angel from a film loop recording only four seconds long. (TV: The Time of Angels)
- Teleport an object back through time to drain its potential chronal energies for sustenance. The very act of sending an object through time, is technically also sending an object through space, since any object moving through time is also moving to a previous physical position in space.
- Teleport an object through space. Rory is teleported by an adolescent Angel from one location in the same time period to another. (TV: The Angels Take Manhattan)
- Implant themselves into the memory of another being and slowly convert that being into what would be eventually another angel. While in this ephemeral state, they were able to affect the mind of the subject including toying with their prey and making them believe they were turning to stone. (TV: The Time of Angels / Flesh and Stone)
- Feeding on all forms of radiation under conditions that would kill most normal forms of life. In addition, while they are not immortal (since they can eventually starve to death) they are very long-lived, even if they don't have enough energy to escape their confines.(TV: The Time of Angels)
- Animate other statues and even turn them into new Angels, including the Statue of Liberty! This is only one moment where we see the potential capacity of the Angels as a serious, world-conquering capable threat.

[image]

- Cause the Statue of Liberty to cross the distance from Ellis Island to the middle of Manhattan, a distance of at least five miles, relatively silently and in a matter of seconds. These Angels were obviously well fed! (TV: Angels Take Manhattan)

[image]

**It is this particular feat (moving the statue of Liberty) which bears questioning:**

- If well-fed Angels could animate and move the Statue of Liberty with that same super-positioning movement they use when they turn out the lights, what are the limits of this ability?
- Could they use this ability, unobserved to escape from a planet's atmosphere?
- And if so, how far is a superposition jump worth in real distance? In space, they would be hard pressed to be seen. Does this mean a jump lasts until they are able to be viewed again?
- Could they cross the vast distances of space, in the blink of an eye? If so, this would explain the Gallifreyan fear of them. The great distances of space would have little meaning to Weeping Angels unless they were observed. The fantastic energies required would mean they would arrive at their targets, very hungry indeed.
- The Weeping Angels are chronovores (feeders on temporal energy). This was something even Gallifreyan Time Lords apparently feared. As long-standing threat to the Gallifreyans, the Weeping Angels were a feared and respected enemy.

> Rassilon declared that the two Time Lords who opposed him, who covered their eyes in the same way as the Weeping Angels, would "stand as monuments to their shame, as did the Weeping Angels of old". (TV: The End of Time)

[image]

- There are unsubstantiated rumors of the Weeping Angels attacking colony worlds in the 33rd Century including the colony of New Moscow. It does not specify whether they used starships, but given their society's apparent lack of technology, it can only be assumed they FLEW there under their own power!

> In the 33rd century, flocks of Weeping Angels swarmed human colony worlds and darkened the sunlight to feed; worlds such as New Moscow were asked to take up arms against them. Some said it would not be possible to oppose such powerful creatures. **([The Brilliant Book 2011](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Brilliant_Book_2011))**

Comment: Those first three angel pictures, where the angel slowly but steadily emerges through the monitor is IMO by far the scariest angel scene ever! A few really good minutes of film making!

Comment: Agreed. This turned me on to the real threat of the Weeping Angels; an enemy unanchored by time or space. Imagine filming an Angel and having it beam its consciousness into millions of minds at the same time...

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Does the last image and the line by Rassilon indicate that Weeping Angels are former Gallifreyans that were somehow turned into that? It would be a nice twist to find that the Time Lords themselves are responsible for unleashing the first Angels upon the universe.

Comment: What's odd about the angel on the monitor, is that he's nearly the _closest_ on the _oldest_ time stamp (11:25:22), _farthest_ on the middle time stamp (11:26:04), and the closest (though without fangs bared) on the _newest_ time stamp (11:27:22).